# Wrap text in list items/buttons instead of hiding the overflow

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm trying to override the default behavior of list items and buttons in jQuery Mobile, which has text which doesn't fit on one line as hidden overflow.

If you view this on a skinny browser window or iPhone you'll see what I mean: http://m.gizmag.com

I'd like to be able to wrap the text in the h3 and p tags of each list item onto new lines.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 69):

Try setting a style of `white-space:normal` for the elements.

I just did this with an anchor (`<a>`) element inside a jQuery Mobile listview-styled `li`, and it worked to wrap the text as I expected. I used Chrome's developer tools to determine where the CSS attributes were coming from and interactively changed them to make it work the way I wanted.

-- 
Derek

Comment: That's a good idea to work it out. It would be nice to create a CSS class that could do that. I also thought of using marquee behaviour.

Comment: Don't know why you didn't get this question.  "white-space: normal" worked perfect for me.

Comment: JQuery Mobile rewrites the list item to have a containing <div class="ui-btn-text"> so this style selector works: div.ui-btn-text { white-space:normal; }

Comment: since it was for a list, this on worked for me:
`.ui-li-desc { white-space: normal; !important}`

Comment: I tried this and it worked, but now on my NavBar that has three buttons, two of them wrap the text (resulting in larger buttons) and one does not, so I'm getting different heights: http://i.imgur.com/kpwesC5.png how can I solve this?

Answer (score 7):

If feasible, enclosing it inside a `<div>` will also make it wrap. (But finding the affected element and declaring `white-space:normal` is the more proper solution)

Source: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/list-items-are-truncating-text-is-there-a-way-around-this